# getting objects of json data

Tags: jquery, json

I am sending a `json` data from `php` to `jquery` and I would like to  get the keys only this is how my data looks like

```
var Jsondata = {
    "code": 1,
    "data": {
        "orange": 0,
        "apple": 1,
        "banana": 2,
        "mango": 0
    },
    "msg": "Success"
}
```

Now I would only like to get the names of the fruits something like this

```
var fruit = //oranger,apple,banana,mango
var value = //0,1,2,0
```

I tried doing this

```
var fruit = Object.keys(Jsondata)
var value = Object.values(Jsondata)
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it like `var value = Object.values(Jsondata.data)`

If you don't add `.data` then you would get `code,data,msg` as `Keys`

**working example**

```js
var Jsondata = {
  "code": 1,
  "data": {
    "orange": 0,
    "apple": 1,
    "banana": 2,
    "mango": 0
  },
  "msg": "Success"
}

var fruit = Object.keys(Jsondata.data)
var value = Object.values(Jsondata.data)

console.log(fruit)
console.log(value)
```

Comment: it doesnt work gives me an
`var fruit = Object.keys(result.data)// uncaught typererror cannot convert undefined or null to object `

Comment: @c319113 Post the entire `result`, since i guess its a type error problem you have.